# Firebase Cloud Firestore Read-Write Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to signup and save user info into firestore. Save operation is fine but i want to search that info but nothing happening. Here is my code

> Signup

```
    firestore
  .collection("users")
  .doc(user.userId)
  .collection("profile")
  .add({ ...user })
  .then(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((u) => {
      if (u) {
        u.updateProfile({
          displayName: user.displayName,
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

> Fetch All users data

```
  firestore
.collection("users")
.get()
.then(function (querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    //doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve by using a similar code as the below one. It very similar to yours, but with some differences, where we separate the referencing to the database and let the `querySnapshot` iterates by itself, so the data can be returned. I usually use this format to return data from collections.

```
var db = admin.firestore()
var usersReference = db.collection("users");

usersReference.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((userDoc) => {
        console.log(userDoc.id)
        var userDocData = userDoc.data()
        console.dir(userDocData)
    })
})
```

This should work, so, in case it doesn't return anything, probably your saving opearation is not working properly. This will return both the user's id and the whole data from it.

Comment: Thank you for your support. You are right my saving operation is not working properly.